# How do I calculate the difference between two dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet that contains:

> - column A: names
> - column B: date of admission
> - column C: date of leave
> - column D: date of death
> - column Z: date of birth

I want to calculate the duration of stay `(date of leave - date of admission)` if date of death is empty, and `(date of leave - date of death)` if there is a date of death.

I have this equation which calculates age:

```
=DATEDIF($Z5,TODAY(),"Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF($Z5,TODAY(),"YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF($Z5,TODAY(),"MD") & " Days"
```

Can it be modified to satisfy my need, or is there another formula to use?

Comment: You might want to check out Chip Pearson's website. He has some pretty nifty formulas for date calculations. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/MainPage.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula gives you requested result with durations expressed in number of days.

```
=IF($D5='',$C5 - $B5, $C5 - $D5)
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to express the date intervals in years, months and days following the logic in your question, the formula is going to be more verbose:

```
=IF($D5='', DATEDIF($B5, $C5, "Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF($B5, $C5, "YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF($B5, $C5, "MD") & " Days", DATEDIF($D5, $C5, "Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF($D5, $C5, "YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF($D5, $C5, "MD") & " Days")
```

In case you are going to use date intervals expressed in years, months and days more often in your documents, it is worth doing calculation in smaller steps in neighboring cells or creating user defined function which will help you to maintain the document further. Just google "user defined function excel" - any of top links provide very good explanations for this.

Comment: If I had posted this answer, it would have been downvoted.

Comment: The OP obviously knows how to find date differences and provided his current formula for age showing how he wants the difference expressed.  The question is how to adapt that formula to include the logic you used here.  Can you improve your answer to address the question?

Comment: Thank you, but I need to display the duration of stay in years, moths, and days, not just days

Comment: @Hany  added more details to the answers

Comment: Thank you very much, but I found some error in the formula it should be
=IF($D5="", DATEDIF($B5, $C5, "Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF($B5, $C5, "YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF($B5, $C5, "MD") & " Days", DATEDIF($B5, $D5, "Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF($B5, $D5, "YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF($B5, $D5, "MD") & " Days")

Also, I would also like to add, if column C (date of leave) is also empty, can the formula calculate duration of stay till today (column B minus today)

Comment: @hany tx - I'll review it today to make sure it correctly answers original question. Of course it can be modified to make it's logic even more elaborated but it would become hardly readable. I recommend that you either create user defined function for date difference in human readable text or use several hidden cells next to final result for doing calculation in small understandable steps. I suggest that you use latter approach - it is much easier for beginners

Comment: @Hany I have read your original question and the last comment and I have found my formula correctly answers your original question as you are asking  to find a difference between date of leave (i.e. column C) and date of death (i.e. column D) if there is a date of death.

Comment: @maoizm I am very sorry, I meant date of admission - date of leave, if date of death is empty; and date of admission - date of death if there is date of death. This is corrected in my comment, in which I asked also for calculating date of admission - today, if both death and leave are empty.